# Labels changing depending on value in other labels

Tags: vb.net, label

I am creating a **POS system** and on the subtotal page I have various labels such as 'cash', 'card', 'voucher' etc.

 Say for example a customers total comes to £20 and they want to pay £10 of it in cash and the other £10 with their card, I am having problems getting the labels to total up as they should. 

The **'total tendered'** label displays 0.000 even though it should say £20.00 and the balance and change labels always display 0.00 even if they should say other. I know this is very basic but I have tried to figure this other for ages now and im getting nowhere.

 I have also tried calling values in from the database but have had no joy with that either. Thanks.
(I only included one payment button click event as they are all the same except for the labels name changing e.g. lblcash.text would say lblcard.text in the card click event.)

`Private Sub btnCash_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCash.Click`

```
    'Payment methods...........??
    '2 cash entries
    'cash and card
    'gift voucher and cash
    'gift voucher and card

    If txtCash.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter amount")
    ElseIf txtCash.Text >= "0.00" Then

        lblCash.Text = txtCash.Text
        lblCash.Text = FormatCurrency(lblCash.Text, 2)

        lblTotTend.Text = (lblCash.Text) + (lblCredit.Text) + (lblVoucher.Text) + (lblOther.Text)
        lblTotTend.Text = FormatCurrency(lblTotTend.Text, 2)

        'DISPLAYING AS £0.00
        lblBALANCE.Text = (lblTOTALDUE.Text) - (lblTotTend.Text)
        lblBALANCE.Text = FormatCurrency(lblBALANCE.Text, 2)

        If lblBALANCE.Text < "0.00" Then
            lblBALANCE.Text = "£0.00"
        End If

        lblChange.Text = (lblTotTend.Text) - (lblTOTALDUE.Text)
        lblChange.Text = FormatCurrency(lblChange.Text, 2)

        If lblChange.Text <= "£0.00" Then
            lblChange.Text = "£0.00"
        End If

        txtCash.Text = ""

        SqlStr = "UPDATE Subtotal SET CASH = '" & lblCash.Text & "'"
        With CMD
            .Connection = CN
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = SqlStr
        End With
        DataP = CMD.ExecuteScalar

        SqlStr = "UPDATE Subtotal SET CHANGE = '" & lblChange.Text & "'"
        With CMD
            .Connection = CN
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = SqlStr
        End With
        DataP = CMD.ExecuteScalar

        SqlStr = "UPDATE Subtotal SET BalanceRemain = '" & lblBALANCE.Text & "'"
        With CMD
            .Connection = CN
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = SqlStr
        End With
        DataP = CMD.ExecuteScalar

        SqlStr = "UPDATE Subtotal SET TotalTendered = '" & lblTotTend.Text & "'"
        With CMD
            .Connection = CN
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = SqlStr
        End With
        DataP = CMD.ExecuteScalar
    End If

    SqlStr = "INSERT INTO SalesLog(ReceiptID) SELECT Id FROM Subtotal"
    With CMD
        .Connection = CN
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = SqlStr
    End With
    DataP = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery

    SqlStr = "INSERT INTO TransactionLog(ReceiptID) SELECT Id FROM Subtotal"
    With CMD
        .Connection = CN
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = SqlStr
    End With
    DataP = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery

    ' Added this statement to try solve problem with totaltendered label
    SqlStr = "SELECT SUM(TotalTendered) FROM Subtotal"
    With CMD
        .Connection = CN
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = SqlStr
    End With
    lblTotTend.Text = CMD.ExecuteScalar
    lblTotTend.Text = FormatCurrency(lblTotTend.Text, 2)

    'UPDATES THE PRICE LABEL TEXTBOX WITH THE LATEST PRICE TOTAL WITHIN THE ACTIVE TABLE!!
    SqlStr = Nothing
    SqlStr = "SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Active"
    With CMD
        .Connection = CN
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = SqlStr
    End With
    lblTOTALDUE.Text = CMD.ExecuteScalar
    ' lblTOTALDUE.Text = FormatCurrency(lblTOTALDUE.Text, 2)

    If lblBALANCE.Text = "£0.00" Then
        Reset()
        Application.DoEvents()
        'TILL DRAWER OPEN
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Me.Close()
        Login.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... You are trying to do maths on strings..  `If lblChange.Text <= "£0.00" Then` will not work the way you expect.

May I suggest that you do not have currency signs in your 'value' lables but have them in a separate lable, it will help in the long run. What happens if your app goes international... or we adopt the Euro... you never know :)

With the currency symbol out of the way all you will need to do is convert your 'value' labels into Doubles using e.g. `CDbl(lblChange.Text)` - making sure that they are not blank in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I took the IF statements out.. I forgot that we had stores in the south of Ireland.. silly me! This is doing my head in.. Once I think I have it working I click something else and, for example, the Balance label has the same value as the Total due and I have no idea how..

Comment: That's the joy of programming :) A couple of tips you could use... instead of checking if a textbox = "" instead of a number I would use If IsNumeric(textbox.Text) Then... you have a numeric value.... meanwhile, to sort your current problems add some breakpoints and check what the lables contain at various points to see where your problem lies.